# How to cancel a Timer before it's finished

Tags: xamarin, timer, xamarin.forms

I am working on a Chat app. After the messages of a chat are loaded and the messages were visible for 5 seconds, I want to send a read confirmation to the server. This is what I've come up with so far:

```
public async void RefreshLocalData()
{
    // some async code to load the messages

    if (_selectedChat.countNewMessages > 0)
    {
        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), SendReadConfirmation);
    }
}
```

When `RefreshLocalData()` is called, I know that either another chat was selected by the user or new messages came in for the current chat. So when `RefreshLocalData()` is called, I have to cancel the current timer to start a new one.

Another situation where I have to cancel the timer is when I navigate to another `Page`. This is no problem, because the whole `ViewModel` is disposed when this happens.

With the code above, if `RefreshLocalData()` is called again but the stated `TimeSpan` of 5 seconds is not over yet, the method is still executing.

Is there a way to cancel the timer (if `RefreshLocalData()` is called again)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have found this answer in the Xamarin forum: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/149877/#Comment_149877

I have changed it a little bit to meet my needs and this solution is working:

```
public class StoppableTimer
{
    private readonly TimeSpan timespan;
    private readonly Action callback;

    private CancellationTokenSource cancellation;

    public StoppableTimer(TimeSpan timespan, Action callback)
    {
        this.timespan = timespan;
        this.callback = callback;
        this.cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        CancellationTokenSource cts = this.cancellation; // safe copy
        Device.StartTimer(this.timespan,
            () => {
                if (cts.IsCancellationRequested) return false;
                this.callback.Invoke();
                return false; // or true for periodic behavior
        });
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref this.cancellation, new CancellationTokenSource()).Cancel();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }
}
```

And this is how I use it in the `RefreshLocalData()` method:

```
private StoppableTimer stoppableTimer;

public async void RefreshLocalData()
{
    if (stoppableTimer != null)
    {
        stoppableTimer.Stop();
    }

    // some async code to load the messages

    if (_selectedChat.countNewMessages > 0)
    {
        if (stoppableTimer == null)
        {
            stoppableTimer = new StoppableTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), SendReadConfirmation);
            stoppableTimer.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            stoppableTimer.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is for using `System.Threading.Timer`, not for `Xamarin.Forms.Device.StartTimer()` and should not be used in a Forms project. Just use `Device.StartTimer()`.

Comment: @BrewMate Why should one not use this in a Forms project? I'm not using `System.Threading.Timer` and it's working perfectly fine with this code

Answer (score 3):

You can try using this class I found, it covers some of the limits to the DeviceTimer:

```
public class MySystemDeviceTimer
{
    private readonly TimeSpan timespan;
    private readonly Action callback;

    private CancellationTokenSource cancellation;

    public bool running { get; private set; }

    public MySystemDeviceTimer(TimeSpan timespan, Action callback)
    {
        this.timespan = timespan;
        this.callback = callback;
        this.cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        running = true;
        start(true);
    }

    private void start(bool continuous)
    {
        CancellationTokenSource cts = this.cancellation;    // safe copy
        Device.StartTimer(this.timespan,
            () =>
            {
                if (cts.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    running = false;
                    return false;
                }
                this.callback.Invoke();
                return continuous;
            });
    }

    public void FireOnce()
    {
        running = true;
        start(false);
        running = false;
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref this.cancellation, new CancellationTokenSource()).Cancel();
    }
}
```

Then for your purpose:

MySystemDeviceTimer timer;

```
    if (timer == null)
    {
       timer = new MySystemDeviceTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), SendReadConfirmation);
       timer.FireOnce();
    }
    else if (timer.running)
       timer.Stop();
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can with `Device.StartTimer()` as long as you return `true` to have the function repeat. I typically handle this through a Boolean variable that I can control in my ViewModel. Something like below:

```
bool shouldRun = true;
public async void RefreshLocalData()
{
    // some async code to load the messages

    if (_selectedChat.countNewMessages > 0)
    {
        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), async() => 
        {
            await SendReadConfirmationAsync()
            return shouldRun;
        });

    }
}

public async Task SendReadConfirmationAsync()
{
    //Do some stuff
    if(we want to stop call)
        shouldRun = false;
}
```

Comment: According to the Xamarin documentation, "While the callback returns true, the timer will keep recurring." - This means the timer would restart after it has finished. This is not what I want to achieve

Comment: Also, your code would always call `SendReadConfirmationAsync`, which should not be the case if `RefreshLocalData` is called again while the timer is running. I think you misunderstood my question